# Oracle DatabaseMetadate get columns for table named USER

Tags: oracle, jdbc

We are using JDBC `DatabaseMetadata` to discover objects in the database. `DatabaseMetadata.getColumns` returns more verbose information -that we really need- than those from `select * from table where 1 = 2`.

Now when I pass the table name -that is a reserved word in Oracle- to getColumns, it fails. If I escape the table name, it does not get results -as it doesn't see a table with that name (i.e. pass the table name `"USER"` instead of `USER`).

Is there a possible way to pass such table -named after reserved words to `getColumns` for Oracle database.

Comment: Try this query: 

  "SELECT * FROM \"USER\"" in Java.

Comment: @HaRdik, As said in the first paragraph, we need the extra details coming from `getColumns`.